# How to access a complex object comming from a datatable cell in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, razor

I have a list of Record objects for the view model (of a Microsoft MVC view) that has the following variables:

```
Variable1 of string type
Variable2 of int type
...
```

I have a razor view for the Record object with a table like the following:

```
<table id="MyTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col1" id="Column1">Column1</th>
            <th class="col2" id="Column2">Column2</th>
            <th class="col3" id="Column3">Column3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Record currentRecord in ListOfRecords)            {
            <tr>
                <td class="col1">X</td>
                <td class="col2">Y</td>
                <td class="col3">@currentRecord</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then in my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function displayData(datainput) {
        alert(datainput.Variable1)
    }

    var oTable = $('#MyTable').DataTable({
        "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "Search all columns:" },
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bPaginate": false
    });

    $('#MyTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        var rowIndex = oTable.cell(this).index().row;
        var theData = oTable.cell(rowIndex,2).data();
        displayData(theData)
    });
});
```

the idea is to display **Variable1** from the record object of that specific row the user clicked on as an alert text, specifically in that **displayData** function. But I am unable to get to that variable in the displayData function. the alert displays **undefined** instead of the value of **Variable1**.  Is there a specific way that I need to pass the parameter?  I'm new at JavaScript/JQuery/Razor views so please help if you can.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that are interested, got it working using Json, first encode it in the view:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (Record currentRecord in ListOfRecords)            {
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">X</td>
            <td class="col2">Y</td>
            <td class="col3">@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(currentRecord))</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Then parse it in the script:

```
$('#MyTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
    var rowIndex = oTable.cell(this).index().row;
    var theData = jQuery.parseJSON(oTable.cell(rowIndex,2).data());
    displayData(theData)
});
```